# How to install Konica Minolta PagePro 1300W to Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

I recently switched to Windows 7 (Home Pro, 64-bit) to discover that my Konica Minolta PagePro 1300W printer no longer works. When connected, Win7 prompts that it can not install a driver for the device.

I have done a lot of googling to solve this problem, with no luck so far. From Konica Minolta official website, I can find drivers only for Windows XP/2000. My current reasoning is that they currently don't and most likely are not going to support Win7 let alone 64-bit version of it for this rather old printer.

So my question is: does anyone have any good tips on how to make this printer work on my system? Is there any other place I could look for drivers, or in generally, do you know any workarounds that could let me printer work?

One of the workaround I have been considering is to install a Windows XP / Ubuntu Linux on a virtualbox and use that system when I really really need to printer. This is of course not the optimal solution, but would let me possibly to use the printer until I buy a newer model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works

> 6/14/20113.33 MBPP1300W win7 x64 v1.0.0.0 Eng.zip
>
> Supported Languages: English

Updated Link (2016-08-18): http://onyxweb.mykonicaminolta.com/OneStopProductSupport/SearchResults?products=979&fileTypes=0&OSs=31

Answer (score 1):

The official Windows 7 compatibility status web site notifies that [the status of 64-bit Win7 compatibility of the given printer is "unknown"](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/Windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Hardware&p=Konica%20Minolta%20PagePro%201300W%20Laser%20Printer&v=Konica%20Minolta&uid=5250216-400&pf=0&pi=9&c=Printers%20%26%20Scanners&sc=Laser%20Printers&os=64-bit). This suggests that at the time of the writing, there is no current, official support for the device.

This status is also confirmed in the manufacturer (Konica Minolta) website. [It states that Windows 7 driver development for the device is current underway](http://kmbs.konicaminolta.us/content/support/windows7.html), and is expected to be released in July 2010.

If printing in Windows is a priority task, a workaround for the problem could be re-installing the system with older Windows version (or using the printer with another device). In any case don't dumb the device yet: the drivers may become shortly available!

Answer (score 0):

This driver is said to be working with [Vista 64-bit](http://download.cnet.com/KONICA-MINOLTA-PagePro-1300W/3010-2116_4-422209.html):

**[KONICA MINOLTA PagePro 1300W 1.3.401.0](http://download.cnet.com/KONICA-MINOLTA-PagePro-1300W/3000-2116_4-422209.html?tag=contentMain;overviewHead)**

If the installer doesn't work, you may rip the driver with [Universal Exctractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract) and install the printer driver manually through the the device manager (let me pick pick / have disk).

*Note: create a system backup or a restore point before forcefully installing drivers.*

Comment: The above driver does not work with Vista or Win7. This is also noted in the spec sheet on the linked page. Therefore, this driver does NOT work on Vista/Win7 64-bit. I'm sorry, but it just doesn't :/